# filtering before actions based on subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An application serves up both http and json requests, the latter via an api which is invoked by a subdomain `api`. However, some before filters are unnecessary or create problems how can such a call

```
prepend_before_action :set_site
```

be avoided when `request.subdomain == 'api'` ?

Comment: as i understand, u wanna reject subdomain `api` calls?

Comment: that on subdomain `api` calls, `set_site` does not run, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I misunderstood your question, but this is what I thought

```
prepend_before_action :set_site unless api_call?

def api_call?
    request.subdomain == "api"
end
```